# pyodbc query working in Spyder but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, sql-server, pycharm, spyder, pyodbc

I am trying to restore a database via `pyodbc`. The original query gets the database into a *'restoring'* state, so I am using the below code to restore the log file and complete the full restore:

```py
import pyodbc 

cnxn_str = (
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    'SERVER=servername;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;' ) 
connection = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str, autocommit=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()
filename = r'x.bak'
sql_query2 = ("""restore log [x] from disk = N'%s'""" % filename)
cursor.execute(sql_query2)
```

When I run this code in Spyder, the restore completes but when I run it in PyCharm, the code runs without errors but the database is still in a *'restoring'* state. Both are using the same version of `pyodbc - 4.0.26`.

Comment: maybe you installed two different python or two different environments?

Comment: They are both using the same version of Python